# vb6 function to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

i got this code in vb6

```
Private Sub pause(ByVal interval As Variant)
    Dim Current As Variant

    Current = Timer
    Do While Timer - Current < Val(interval)
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

How do I convert in vb.net? I have tried this way but it doesn't works.

Where is the mistake?

```
Private Sub pause(ByVal interval As Single)            
      Dim newDate As Date    
      newDate = DateAndTime.Now.AddSeconds(interval)

      While DateAndTime.Now.Second <> newDate.Second                
          Application.DoEvents()           
      End While    
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following is the best conversion of the original code (subtly different to andygrips answer):

```
Private Sub Pause(ByVal seconds As Integer)
    Dim current As Date

    current = DateTime.Now
    Do While (DateTime.Now - current).TotalSeconds < seconds
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note however that the use of DoEvents in .NET is best avoided altogether

Comment: @yonghan79 You need to have a look into multi threading - check out the [BackGroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Thanks,i will try it.By the way do you mind to take a look at my code,i'll send the code if it's ok with you. :) I have tried the converted sub,it gives me an error,is it possible caused by Application.DoEvents?

Comment: Sorry if i just reply now,i have been away for a while.It shows me mscrolib.dll error,but then i add Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000),it works.Thanks for you help. :)

Comment: How are you?Can i ask for your help again?It still doesn't work as i expected.I post the code here [CODE](http://pastebin.com/zeycXgFv).I use a timer with interval=500.It gives me like this <img src="http://i575.photobucket.com/albums/ss197/yonghan79/error-2.jpg" border="0" alt="Photobucket"></a>.Could you help me pointing where is the mistake?Thanks.

Comment: @yonghan79 You need to start a new question posting the code and the error you are getting, that way you will get a better response

Answer (score 1):

It will only escape the `While` if the `Now` seconds equal `newDate` seconds. Try this instead:

```
    Private Sub pause(ByVal interval As Single)
       Dim waitUntil As Date = DateAndTime.Now.AddSeconds(interval)
       While DateAndTime.Now < waitUntil
           Application.DoEvents()
       End While
    End Sub
```

Also can I suggest that you name your methods using PascalCase (the first letter of the method name is capitalised).

Comment: According to the microsoft standard naming conventions for .NET, private members should be in camelCase, and public members should be in PascalCase.

Comment: I don't believe Microsoft actually say that you should use camelCase for private members, only that you should use PascalCase for public members.

I use PascalCase for all methods because I find it more readable.

Comment: @andygjp - There are Pros and cons to all naming conventions but in the end resistance is futile!

Comment: Ah, yup, you're right, the official guidelines don't specify the correct casing for private members.  So, it's left up to each developer to decide on their own naming convention for those.